# Can you disable wagtail admin url?

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to completely disable url login of wagtail admin on production. as i want to setup a replicated environment in a Bastian box so i only allow my ip address when im making changes

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the admin urls from your url config?

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # uncomment the following line
    # url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    url(r'^pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

Comment: Yes we tried this but it breaks everything for some reason

Comment: @user8585282 What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: My apologies, on re-looking at this the above works exactly as i wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can blocking/allowing IP-addresses in Nginx

```
location /admin/ {
  allow XXX.XX.XX.XX;  ## Your specific IP
  deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user8585282: If you're trying to filter URIs in Nginx, you can do so by editing the Nginx config file for you site (in Ubuntu it's at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-project).

Then, in the server block, add the following code (you can use IPv4 and IPv6 with CIDR).

```html
server {

...

    #restricts wagtail admin to this IP CIDR Block
    location = /admin {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        allow XX.XX.XX.XX/24;
        deny all;
    }

    #restricts django admin to this IP CIDR Block
    location = /django-admin {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        allow XX.XX.XX.XX/24;
        deny all;
    }

...

}
```